# custom onChange in fromik library (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am new to formik library and I have implemented successfully the problem is I have a custom component for selection and I can seem to make it to work with formik.

Here is my implementation:

```
const formik = useFormik({
initialValues: {
  title: "",
  message: "",
  selected: [],
},
validate,
onSubmit: (values) => {
  console.log("SUBMITTED: ", values);
},


 });

  ...



<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
       ...
            <Col>
              <Select
                isDisabled={
                  formik?.values?.selected?.includes("All") ? true : false
                }
                isMulti
                name="users"
                options={options}
                className="basic-multi-select"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                // onChange={(value) => setSelected(value)}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
              />
              {formik.errors.selected ? (
                <div className="form-error">{formik.errors.selected}</div>
              ) : null}
            </Col>
          </div>
          <Button
            size="lg"
            color="warning"
            className="notification-send-button"
            type="submit"
            onClick={formik.handleSubmit}
          >
            SUBMIT
          </Button>
        </form>
```

The custom component is the `<Select>` and was wondering how to change the value in formik when its changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know if this will work without seeing your code for component `<Select>`, but since it's a Custom Input, you'll need to combine it with `setFieldValue()`:

```
<Select
  onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue('selected', value)}
  //... other props
/>
```